# Azure Blob Copy from presigned to presigned url

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

I'm trying to copy an azure blob from one account to another.
I have a destination and a source url with their shared access key.

the request that i've done are:

```
PUT on  [url with and without sastoken]

Authorization: "SharedAccessSignature [sas token encoded and decoded]"
x-ms-copy-source: "[sourceUri with and without sastoken]"
x-ms-copy-source-authorization: "SharedAccessSignature [sas token encoded and decoded]"
x-ms-requires-sync: "true"
x-ms-date: [example: 2023-01-03T17:27:02Z]
x-ms-version: [taken from destination sastoken]

empty body
```

In the documentations is not specified the content of the authorization header i've found it on internet.
i've tried with and without x-ms-copy-source-authorization header that is reported in the documentation for copy from url but not in copy documentation
i'm sure that source url is valid why befor these request i put a file on this blob.
destination url is retrieved from an external service and i have no resolution from my machine i can test only after deploy.

if you have any ideas, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAS URL for both source and destination blobs, then you would do a `PUT` operation using the destination blob SAS URL.

You don't need `Authorization` header as the destination blob URL already has the authorization information (in the SAS URL).

You would need to specify source blob SAS URL for `x-ms-copy-source`.

You need not specify `x-ms-copy-source-authorization` as the source blob URL already has the authorization information (in the SAS URL).

You need not specify `x-ms-date` and `x-ms-version`.

To summarize, your request should look something like:

```
PUT on  [destination blob SAS URL]

x-ms-copy-source: "[source blob SAS URL]"
x-ms-requires-sync: "true"
empty body
```